# How to set up frame-ancestors directive in Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, security, yarnpkg, content-security-policy

My team is currently working to prevent clickjacking attacks and would like to add the frame-ancestors directive to our application. We have an Angular app that is served by Yarn. The directive we want to activate is Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'.

We have tried adding frame-ancestors to the meta tag of our index.html page but we receive a warning that this has no effect:

We have also found options to configure it on the server side but there is no information for how to do that with Yarn.

How can we activate Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' in an Angular application?

Comment: Yarn is a package manager, not an HTTP server. You might use it to launch an HTTP server, but how you configure *that* depends on which HTTP server you are actually using. Hopefully you aren't planning to use the Angular development server (which I assume is Webpack) in production.

Comment: Thank you Quentin for informing me. Seems like I need to figure out which HTTP server we're using.